# The correct way of using the nouns that are both countable and uncountable

Tags: uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns

Which one is correct and why?

> 1)I like sausage.
>
> 2)I like sausage**s**.

As far as I know sausage is both a countable and uncountable noun,in my point of view when we are talking about sausage in general we shouldn't use (**s**),so sentence **(1)** seems better to me but I've heard sentence **(2)** alot,as well.

I'd be thankful if someone explains when I should use sausage as a countable noun and when as an uncountable one.

Comment: Non-count "sausage" denotes a food substance, whereas count "sausage(s) denotes an individual unit consisting of that substance. For example, "I don't like sausage" (non-count) vs "We have three sausages left" (count).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are correct, but the connotation is different.

> I like sausage.

Indicates that you like the food in general.

> I like sausages.

Brings to mind an image of either (a) various types of sausage, or (b) eating one or more sausage links as a meal.

In general, the second sentence sounds more like something I would hear in the UK than the US, but I would defer to a native speaker of UK English on that. "I like sausages" sounds grammatical but very slightly awkward to me as a US English speaker.